# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: imagick: Unable to initialize module

Tags: php5

I am getting following error when installed with lib imagick, but able to see the imagick module. Could you please check and help to resolve the issue without uninstalling the imagick module. Thank you

Error:

```
php_errors.log:[22-Jun-2020 17:40:47 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: imagick: Unable to initialize module
php_errors.log:Module compiled with module API=20100525
php_errors.log:PHP    compiled with module API=20160303
```

Module:

```
imagick

imagick module => enabled
imagick module version => 3.4.4
imagick classes => Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator, ImagickKernel
Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version => ImageMagick 6.9.10-68 Q16 x86_64 2020-04-01 https://imagemagick.org
Imagick using ImageMagick library version => ImageMagick 6.9.10-68 Q16 x86_64 2020-04-01 https://imagemagick.org
ImageMagick copyright => © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
ImageMagick release date => 2020-04-01
ImageMagick number of supported formats:  => 230
ImageMagick supported formats => 3FR, 3G2, 3GP, AAI, AI, ART, ARW, AVI, AVS, BGR, BGRA, BGRO, BMP, BMP2, BMP3, BRF, CAL, CALS, CANVAS, CAPTION, CIN, CIP, CLIP, CMYK, CMYKA, CR2, CRW, CUR, CUT, DATA, DCM, DCR, DCX, DDS, DFONT, DNG, DOT, DPX, DXT1, DXT5, EPDF, EPI, EPS, EPS2, EPS3, EPSF, EPSI, EPT, EPT2, EPT3, ERF, EXR, FAX, FILE, FITS, FRACTAL, FTP, FTS, G3, G4, GIF, GIF87, GRADIENT, GRAY, GRAYA, GROUP4, GV, H, HALD, HDR, HISTOGRAM, HRZ, HTM, HTML, HTTP, HTTPS, ICB, ICO, ICON, IIQ, INFO, INLINE, IPL, ISOBRL, ISOBRL6, JNG, JNX, JPE, JPEG, JPG, JPS, JSON, K25, KDC, LABEL, M2V, M4V, MAC, MAGICK, MAP, MASK, MAT, MATTE, MEF, MIFF, MKV, MNG, MONO, MOV, MP4, MPC, MPEG, MPG, MRW, MSL, MSVG, MTV, MVG, NEF, NRW, NULL, ORF, OTB, OTF, PAL, PALM, PAM, PANGO, PATTERN, PBM, PCD, PCDS, PCL, PCT, PCX, PDB, PDF, PDFA, PEF, PES, PFA, PFB, PFM, PGM, PGX, PICON, PICT, PIX, PJPEG, PLASMA, PNG, PNG00, PNG24, PNG32, PNG48, PNG64, PNG8, PNM, PPM, PREVIEW, PS, PS2, PS3, PSB, PSD, PTIF, PWP, RADIAL-GRADIENT, RAF, RAS, RAW, RGB, RGBA, RGBO, RGF, RLA, RLE, RMF, RW2, SCR, SCT, SFW, SGI, SHTML, SIX, SIXEL, SPARSE-COLOR, SR2, SRF, STEGANO, SUN, SVG, SVGZ, TEXT, TGA, THUMBNAIL, TIFF, TIFF64, TILE, TIM, TTC, TTF, TXT, UBRL, UBRL6, UIL, UYVY, VDA, VICAR, VID, VIFF, VIPS, VST, WBMP, WMF, WMV, WMZ, WPG, X, X3F, XBM, XC, XCF, XPM, XPS, XV, XWD, YCbCr, YCbCrA, YUV

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
imagick.locale_fix => 0 => 0
imagick.progress_monitor => 0 => 0
imagick.skip_version_check => 0 => 0
```

Comment: How did you install PHP and the imagick module?

Comment: PHP was installed earlier, recently we have installed lib imagick. But it is throwing following error.  php_errors.log:[22-Jun-2020 17:40:47 UTC] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: imagick: Unable to initialize module php_errors.log:Module compiled with module API=20100525 php_errors.log:PHP compiled with module API=20160303.   Could you please check and help. Thank you

Comment: I already saw the error message. I did not ask about that. I asked exactly what method you used to install PHP earlier, and what method you used to install the PHP imagick module recently.

Comment: Hi Michael,
thank you for responding.

Comment: Hi Michael,
thank you for responding.
I am sorry to say I haven't either installed PHP or imagick from my end. It was installed earlier and it is not working because of this error. 
I tried to install from this steps provided in link "https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-php-imagemagick-on-centos-7"  again to check if it works, but it didn't work and has thrown error like below. Please check and help. Thank you

I tried with steps
1: yum groupinstall " Development Tools"  -y
result: Dependency Installed:
  python-srpm-macros.noarch 0:3-32.el7

Comment: Updated:  doxygen.x86_64 1:1.8.5-4.el7  elfutils.x86_64 0:0.176-4.el7  git.x86_64 0:1.8.3.1-23.el7_8  patch.x86_64 0:2.7.1-12.el7_7  rcs.x86_64 0:5.9.0-7.el7  redhat-rpm-config.noarch 0:9.1.0-88.el7.centos  rpm-build.x86_64 0:4.11.3-43.el7 rpm-sign.x86_64 0:4.11.3-43.el7  systemtap.x86_64 0:4.0-11.el7

Comment: 2: yum install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel -y
result: Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.webruimtehosting.nl,  * epel: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net,  * extras: ams.edge.kernel.org,  * updates: ams.edge.kernel.org,  * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com, Package ImageMagick-6.9.10.68-3.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version, Package ImageMagick-devel-6.9.10.68-3.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version, Nothing to do

Comment: 3: yum install php-pear : result: Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile,  * base: mirror.webruimtehosting.nl,  * epel: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net,  * extras: linux.cs.uu.nl,  * updates: mirror.ams1.nl.leaseweb.net,  * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Package 1:php-pear-1.9.4-21.el7.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: 4: yum install php-devel
result:
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.webruimtehosting.nl
 * epel: epel.mirror.liteserver.nl
 * extras: centos.mirror.triple-it.nl
 * updates: ams.edge.kernel.org
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Package php-devel-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: 5: pecl install Imagick: pecl/Imagick is already installed and is the same as the released version 3.4.4, install failed

Comment: 6: php -i | grep Imagick : PHP Warning:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  Unknown: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in Unknown on line 0

Comment: imagick classes => Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator, ImagickKernel, Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version => ImageMagick 6.9.10-68 Q16 x86_64 2020-04-01 https://imagemagick.org, Imagick using ImageMagick library version => ImageMagick 6.9.10-68 Q16 x86_64 2020-04-01 https://imagemagick.org

Comment: I tried, but you still haven't answered the request for information I asked a week ago. **How did you install PHP and the imagick module?**